# Querying MongoDB with values from a text file

Tags: mongodb, text-files

I've been handed a list of 500+ email addresses in a text file and been asked to find out how many of them exist as customer emails in our MongoDB database.

What is the quickest way of finding out which of those emails in the text file currently exist in the "Customer.Email" field of my collection?

Can I use text file of emails as parameters for a query, for instance?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: If you really want to know what is the query with the highest performance maybe you should give us several possibilities to judge. If you want some code, I think you should as first thing give it a try by yourself...

Comment: I'm not after query performance; I'm literally after the quickest method to take this list of emails in a text file, query the DB and have the results available to me?

Comment: I don't think the question is invalid. The OP is asking for the best approach to achieve this. I find the question interesting and I would like to know as well. I am working on a solution. I am thinking a file reader then put the contents in an array. You could then compare the entries in mongo to the objects in the array?

Comment: I'm wondering whether there's some native functionality that facilitates this. As I mention in the question, if one could pass a comma-separated file into an $in statement... or something like that, that'd be sweet.

Comment: Show us the format the txt file is. such as email@email.com 1 per line or email@email.com, foo@foo.com, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick,

I am assuming your `txt file` is in this format,

```
test1@test.com
test2@test.com
test3@test.com
test4@test.com
test5@test.com
test6@test.com
test7@test.com
test8@test.com 
test9@test.com 
test10@test.com
```

upload the `text.txt` file to the server for to convert it to an `js array`

you can do that with something like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>File Reader</title>


</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <script>
            function getData() { //this will read file and send information to other function

                var xmlhttp;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                } else {

                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

                        var lines = xmlhttp.responseText;

                        intoArray(lines);

                    }


                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "text.txt", true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }


            getData();

            function intoArray(lines) {


                var lineArr = lines.split('\n');

                //just to check if it works output lineArr[index] as bellow*

                lineArr.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
                    console.log(arrayItem);
                });

            }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

At this point the email address in the `txt file` will be in an `array` so you can query the `mongodb` with the `$in Operator` like this,

```
db.Customers.find( {CustomerEmail: { $in [$myArray] } })
```